# std::unordered_map<std::String, myClass*> - does std::unordered_map::erase() call myClass' DTor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have some `unordered_map` of pointers to class instances, would erasing an object from that map also delete the instance?

(rewording the question:) If I wanted to delete that instance, which version would be right?

```
if(it != map.end())
{
    delete it->second;
    map.erase(it);
}
```

or simply

```
if(it != map.end())
    map.erase(it);
```

?

UPDATE: as suggested by many people, I moved to using `shared_ptr`, and it works great!

Comment: `erase` by itself would leak the pointer. Consider using a map of `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: If it needs to take ownership of the pointers, why not use a `unique_ptr`, which will delete the object for you?

Comment: Thank you.  The map is only a lookup-by-name, the rest of my app needs to use the pointers, so I take other precautions to not use a freed pointer.

Comment: You can also use `std::shared_ptr`, or you can just store the actual object inside the map: `std::unordered_map<std::string, myClass>`.

Comment: @bames53: thank you for that hint, but I might add: one might get into troubles directly storing class instances in the map.  While this is perfectly ok to do so, it depends on your actual program and what it really does.  In my case this is not an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, and since this is tagged C++11 you should be using `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr` to manage your object pointers in the first place, e.g.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<myClass>>
```

Even if you religiously make sure that your pointers are `delete`d before any call to `erase`, you still have to consider what would happen in the event of an exception, or if you assign something else to the same key, or any number of other possibilities that might leak. Unless you have a very good reason to use `new` and `delete`, don't; stick to `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_unique` / `std::make_shared`, it's safer and makes your code easier to read.

Comment: +1. **And** even if you have a very good reason to use `new` and `delete`, think about it some more and see if that reason is actually good enough to warrant all the risks and hassle raw memory management brings.

Comment: Thank you, I'll think about it and eventually do that.